# Open New Outlook Message from C#

Tags: c#, outlook, html-email

I am looking to generate an Outlook message from within my program, I am able to build and send from within the program or build and save, what I would like is to build then display to allow the user to manually select recipients from the AD listings... The code below is a mixup of samples here and other tutorial sites however none I can find just build then "display" the email without saving a draft or sending it from within the program...

also I am looking to find a way i can create a UNC link inside of an email IE: write out a path to the users folder \\unc\path\%USERNAME% or the likes

```
private void sendEmailOutlook(string savedLocation, string packageName)
    {
        try
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

            oMsg.HTMLBody = "Attached is the required setup files for your <i><b>soemthing</i></b> deployment package.";
            oMsg.HTMLBody += "\nPlease save this file to your network user folder located.<br /><br/>\\\\UNC\\data\\users\\%USER%\\";
            oMsg.HTMLBody += "\nOnce saved please boot your Virtual machine, locate and execute the file at <br /> <br />\\\\UNC\\users\\%USER%\\";

            int pos = (int)oMsg.Body.Length +1;
            int attachType = (int)Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlAttachmentType.olByValue;

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment oAttach = oMsg.Attachments.Add(savedLocation, attachType, pos, packageName);

            oMsg.Subject = "something deployment package instructions";
            oMsg.Save();

        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Email Failed", ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.display.aspx) doesn't work?

Comment: @Herdo It is throwing me an error, but I can work through that, It apears to be what I am looking for for the first part, Are you capable of answering the second part re: UNC paths for the end user...

Comment: Due to you are using a HTML format: Did you try to use a simple html-link element (`<a></a>`)?

Comment: @herdo, thats not the problem its dynamically generating the userfolder.... every user has a folder under their username, I know windows uses UNC paths all the time but have no idea how to do this so the receiving individual would actually see their own folder...

Comment: I have to disappoint you. Your attempt won't work like this, due to e-mail clients don't resolve any paths with "placeholders".

Are you using this in your company? If yes, i guess everyone has a specific smtp-account that matches the user folder?

Comment: @herdo that would be correct everyone has their own accounts everything matches up of course

Comment: Well, 2 options for you, that i ran over so far (I took the first one in my solutions):

**1.:** Let the user edit a template. When the user sends the template, send 1 e-mail per recipient with replaced path by the user specific data. Then withdraw the template (Note: there will be one sent e-mail per recipient).

**2.:** Write an Add-In for all your co-workers e-mail clients that resolves the paths when receiving the e-mails.


*I know, these aren't maybe the best solutions, but they do their job :)*

Comment: Thanks I will look into the second option since it seems more of a long term solution even if its more complicated to implement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

oMsg.Subject = "something deployment package instructions";
oMsg.BodyFormat = OlBodyFormat.olFormatHTML;
oMsg.HTMLBody = //Here comes your body;
oMsg.Display(false); //In order to display it in modal inspector change the argument to true
```

Regarding the link to the folder you should be able to use(in case that you know User Name):

```
<a href="C:\Users\*UserName*">Link</a>
```

A lot of companies have their employees user names attached to address entries (looks something like "John Doe(Jdoe)" where Jdoe is a username).
when your user select a recipients or tries to send the email you could catch those event, and do something like

```
foreach (Outlook.Recipient r in oMsg.Recipients)
{
    string username = getUserName(r.Name);//  or r.AddressEntry.Name instead of r.Name
    oMsg.HTMLBody += "<a href='C:\\Users\\" + username  + "'>Link</a>"
}
oMsg.Save();
oMsg.Send();
```

where `getUserName()` is a method that extracts only the userName (Could use substring or RegEx).

- Make sure that mail's body is a valid HTML
- /n won't give you a new line you should use `<br>` insted.

Comment: Thanks I had it worked out with the coversations with @Herdo previously all but the link that is, However the username will not be known at runtime, it will be added after via outlook AD,