# Showing Outlook instead of displaying a message in C#.Net

Tags: c#

```
Process[] pName = Process.GetProcessesByName("OUTLOOK");

if (pName.Length == 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Outlook is not running."); // Open Outlook a new.
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Outlook is running."); // Do not re-open Outlook.
}
```

How can I replace the MessageBox that tells the user that Outlook is already running to showing the Microsoft Outlook application on top of all applications in C#.Net?

Comment: That might help you!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19137815/open-new-outlook-message-from-c-sharp

Comment: @ThiagoVinicius Thank you for your reply to my question, I really appreciate it, but that's not what I'm looking for... Please review my question above. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2636721/bring-another-processes-window-to-foreground-when-it-has-showintaskbar-false

Comment: I think this is what you are trying to do, switching to an already running process:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2315561/correct-way-in-net-to-switch-the-focus-to-another-application